# Как добавлять код ещё не существующему элементу?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

У меня есть кнопка которая создаёт другие кнопки, и мне нужно что бы в новых кнопках был уже написан код. Не знаю как это сделать. Надеюсь, что это возможно. Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 3):

Я так понимаю, что под `кнопка которая создаёт другие кнопки` подразумевается то, что при нажатии на неё создаются новые кнопки. Если это так, то вам просто необходимо подписать нужный метод на событие кнопки `кнопка.OnClick`.

Допустим главная кнопка называется `MainButton`, а метод (код), который должны вызывать новые кнопки - `DoSomething`. Тогда в коде это будет выглядеть так:

```
private void MainButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newButton = new Button(); // создаем кнопку
    newButton.OnClick += DoSomething; //подписываем ее на метод DoSomething
}

//сам метод на который мы подписываем новосозданную кнопку
private void DoSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ваш код
}
```

Comment: я это знал. Но не знаю как это в код перевести! Извините но я новичок. И только изучаю c#

Comment: @Анонимчел добавил код

Comment: а куда мне добавлять код?

Comment: @Анонимчел код для новых кнопок в метод `DoSomething`, строку `newButton.OnClick += DoSomething;` туда, где вы создаёте новые кнопки

Comment: понял Спасибо!!!